# How to debug a driver file (INF) in vs2012

Tags: windbg, wdk

I followed the instruction in the url below till Step 10 to develop a helloworld kernel-mode driver. Everything seems all right. In Step 11, I ran windbg command **bp kmdfsmall!DriverEntry**, then F5. However, this breakpoint is never hit. I want to enter DriveEntry and then run line by line. I guess I missed something. Can anyone kindly advise?

Host: Win8 64 bit

Target: Win7 32 bit

VMWare 9, VS2012 Pro, WDK 8

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time you hit that stage the driver is already loaded and DriverEntry has already been called. To step through DriverEntry you need to set a breakpoint with bu:

bu kmdfsmall!driverentry

And then disable/enable the device on the target. This will cause the driver to be reloaded and your breakpoint hit.

FYI your topic is misleading. The INF is the installation file used to install your driver image, the driver itself is the SYS file.

Comment: INF was a mistake. Sorry about that. Your solution works. Many thanks!